# How to use MAKECAB.EXE

Tags: windows

The syntax is:

```
MAKECAB  [/Vn] [/D variable=value ...] [/L directory] source [destination]
MAKECAB  [/Vn] [/D variable=value ] /F directives_file [...]
```

If no directives_file is used and the last parameter destination is specified, e.g. as "C:\Test", the cab will be generated in **C:\Test**.

But when a directives_file is used, the cab is generated in a subfolder **\disk1**.

What should be specified in the directives_file to have the same result as in the first case, i.e. the cab is generated in a specified folder?

Comment: I think you are asking for the /L option

Comment: Hm... But how to specify in the directives_file?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

To get the cab with the name MyCabinet.cab in the folder C:\MyCabFiles, the following two lines must be included in the directives_file:

```
.Set CabinetName1="MyCabinet.cab"
.Set DiskDirectoryTemplate="C:\MyCabFiles"
```